# Cholesky rank 1 update

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to use square root UKF method for parameter estimation. My problem is with the MATLAB `cholupdate`!

In order to use the Cholesky factor of rank 1 in the SR-UKF you need to calculate the *cholupdate*{S,u,+-v} but MATLAB code `cholupdate` is just accepting 1 as v. like *cholupdate*{S,u,+-1}.

Anyone has this problem before?

[This is the paper](http://ece.ut.ac.ir/Classpages/S87/ECE150/Papers/Kalman-Filter/merwe01a.pdf) I am using for SRF UKF.

Comment: http://ece.ut.ac.ir/Classpages/S87/ECE150/Papers/Kalman-Filter/merwe01a.pdf

this is the paper I am using for SR UKF algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third input of `cholupdate(R,X,v)` is a single character (`'+'` or `'-'`) indicating either `A + X*X'` or `A - X*X'` (update or downdate).  If you want `v` to scale `X` via `A + v*X*X'`, you will have to build that into `X`:

```
>> A = pascal(4)
>> R = chol(A)
>> x = [0 0 0 1].'; %' update
>> v = 1.2
>> xs = sqrt(v)*x;
>> isequal(A + xs*xs.',A + s*(x*x.'))
ans =
     1
```

Then you can use `cholupdate(R,xs,'+')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot chappjc! your method solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

The last line is `v` to be equal:

```
A = pascal(4)

R = chol(A)

x = [0 0 0 1].'%' update

v = 1.2

xs = sqrt(v)*x

ss=isequal(A + xs*xs.',A + v*(x*x.'))
```

Comment: Sometimes the isequal give a non-definit positive matrix because sqrt(v) is not enough precise. Then use: ss=isequal(A+ round(xs*xs.'), A+ v*(x*x.'))